# Finding all Admins using Rails Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I find all admins using Rails 6 active record associations?

I have the following classes:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :relationships
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :relationships
end

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :group_id, presence: true
  validates :admin, inclusion: [true, false]
```

I'd like to add admins as a has_many relationship in Group.
Here's my first attempt at doing so:

```
has_many :admins, class_name: "User", through: :relationships
```

How would I filter those users whose relationship to the group has the admin attribute set to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Associations can be scoped](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) using the normal query syntax.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  has_many :admins,
    -> { where({ relationships: { admin: true} }) },
    through: :relationships,
    source: :user
end
```

`source` is necessary because otherwise it will try to do the has_many through `Relationships.admins`.

`group.admins` is equivalent to `group.users.where({ relationships: { admin: true} })`.

Comment: Beautiful. Chefs kiss.

Comment: Wait, I'm getting the following error: `Error:
GroupsControllerTest#test_valid_group_update:
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "admin" or :admins in model Relationship. Try 'has_many :admins, :through => :relationships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or group?
    app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:81:in \`admin_user'
    test/controllers/groups_controller_test.rb:134:in \`block in <class:GroupsControllerTest>'
`

Comment: @izaguirrejoe My mistake. With a has_many :through it needs a `source` to infer the relationship. Else it's looking for `Relationship.admins`.

Answer (score 0):

You could've modified your Group model to something like:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  scope :admins, -> { where(relationships: { admin: true }) }

  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :relationships
end
```

From it you can use `Group.joins(:users).admins` to get groups with assoiciated admins.